# jquery not working in popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, popup, popupwindow

I have code to submit form in jquery but all these need to happen in a popup window.

I have minimized my script to the simplest form without the ajax calls and other for readability purpose, I want to know how to achieve a simple jquery code initiated in a popup window many thanks

```js
$("button").on('click', function(event) {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  if (id == "go") {
    var w = window.open("", "popupWindow", "width=550, height=550, scrollbars=no");
    var $w = $(w.document.body);

    $w.html('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"><\/scr' + 'ipt><script>$.noConflict(); jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {$("body").show("fast", function() {$(".pal").focusin(function(event) {/* Act on the event */ $(".er").remove(); $(this).css({backgroundColor: "#0b4cb9", boxShadow: "0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)"}); }); }); });<\/scr' + 'ipt>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="padding:10px 40px;" id="go">go</button>
```

But I always get the following error:

> VM23221:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I have tried no-conflict and loading full script from external server.

Comment: You don't have that error in the snippet above. So maybe you have not inserted jQuery import `script` element before your own script?

Comment: And put button  onclick inside document ready order way the window not will open

Comment: thank you all but putting it in or outside still gives me the error, i am suspecting jquery is not being loaded into the popup window

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you load Jquery before you use it.

Comment: thanks for your reply but there is no way for me reproduce my problem with the snippet above

Comment: jquery is being loaded in the real code but it doesnt load